# configure: error: libavcodec versions 55 and later are not s

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I get this error when I ./configure vlc-2.0.8

> configure: error: libavcodec versions 55 and later are not supported
>   yet

I already downloaded the gits for ffmpeg, lame-3.98.4, x264, yasm-1.2.0 and installed them successfully. As I googled this error, I found out the following links:

https://patches.videolan.org/patch/1141/

http://www.mail-archive.com/vlc-commits@videolan.org/msg16415.html

these links include a patch and suggest that this patch shall be substituted or added (i don't know) to the configure.ac file which exists inside the my vlc-2.0.8 folder.

As the links do not contain a step by step instruction in order to understand what commands to use and how to add the patch file, I would thank if you guide me through that.

Cheers,

Comment: Well, what version of `libavcodec` did you install? Clearly, it is too new for VLC.

Comment: Yes, it is. I had to patch a file to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

What I did is to add the following patch to configure.ac file:

```
 AC_ARG_ENABLE(avcodec,
 [  --enable-avcodec        libavcodec codec (default enabled)])
 AS_IF([test "${enable_avcodec}" != "no"], [
-  PKG_CHECK_MODULES(AVCODEC,[libavcodec >= 54.25.0 libavutil >= 51.22.0], [
-    AS_IF([test "${enable_sout}" != "no"], [
-      PKG_CHECK_EXISTS([libavcodec < 55],, [
-        AC_MSG_ERROR([libavcodec version 55 requires --disable-sout.])
-      ])
-    ])
+  PKG_CHECK_MODULES(AVCODEC,[libavcodec >= 53.34.0 libavutil >= 51.22.0], [
     PKG_CHECK_EXISTS([libavcodec < 56],, [
       AC_MSG_ERROR([libavcodec versions 56 and later are not supported yet.])
     ])
```

next, I ran

```
# autoconf
```

now, when running does not prompt the error for not supporting newer versions of libavcodec :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a compatibility problem with this version of VLC (2.0.8) and the development version of ffmpeg on which it depends.

From: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/40025:

> This will "just work" when VLC is updated to 2.1 which will happen
>   well before ffmpeg becomes 2.0

Without manually patching (as you've done), you may have to wait for v2.1 for a clean fix.